# Html5 and Css3 - Horizontal navigation bar issues

Tags: html, css, css-float, clearfix

I am designing a webpage. I have two levels of navigation, the social media buttons on the first level and later a navigation bar.  I am having issues getting the background colour of the navigation bar to go the complete length of the webpage, at present it starts and stops with the navigation bar. I am guessing it is an issue related to the location or my coding of the clearfix? Anyways I would appreciate your advice. My coding is below, I have attached a photo of my site so you can see what it looks like.

[image]

My Html code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header id="header" role="banner">
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/title.png" alt="logo" width="1018" height="140"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="social">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/SaveADHCNSW#" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="32" height="32"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Save-NSW-Government-Disability-
    Services-ADHC-709029659182219/" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="32" height="32"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCS0HQwz4LWWGS4AZhb5Ry3w" target="_blank"><img src="images/youtube.png" alt="Youtube" width="32" height="32"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="clearfix">
    </div>
    <nav id="page_nav">
      <div class="menu">
        <ul id="navmenu">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Get Involved</a><span class="darrow">&#9660;</span>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="socialmedia.html">Social Media</a></li>
              <li><a href="unionmeeting.html">Union Meetings</a></li>
              <li><a href="rally.html">Rally</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a><span class="darrow">&#9660;</span>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="shrewsnews.html">Shrew's News</a></li>
              <li><a href="update.html">Update</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="contacts.html">Contact Us</a></l>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="clearfix">
      </div>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
</div>
```

My Css:

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 1366px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: black;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 50px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

#social {
  float: right;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#social ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

#clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#page_nav {
  background-color: #c50a13;
}

ul#navmenu {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto auto 5px auto;
}

ul.submenu {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul#navmenu li {
  outline: 1px solid white;
  width: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
  color: #26b0f1;
}

ul#navmenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: #c50a13;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}

ul#navmenu .submenu a {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
  background-color: white;
  color: #c50a13;
}

ul#navmenu ul.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  left: 0px;
}

ul#navmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}

.darrow {
  font-size: 14pts;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 1px;
  color: dodgerblue;
}
```

Comment: To begin with you have an extra closing div tag before you close your nav

Comment: No that tag closes my wrapper div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

You forgot something in your CSS `clearfix`.

```
#clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: ''; /* add me */
}
```

In addition, you have some errors in your HTML which can affect rendering in different ways in different browsers.

**[1]** Invalid close tag for an `<li>`

**[2]** Extra `</div>` before the close of your `</nav>`.

**[3]** Duplicate IDs: `id="clearfix"`

First, fix the duplicate IDs. In your CSS, change this:

```
#clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

To this:

```
.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Here is your HTML without errors.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header id="header" role="banner">
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/title.png" alt="logo" width="1018" height="140"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="social">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/SaveADHCNSW#" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="32" height="32"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Save-NSW-Government-Disability-Services-ADHC-709029659182219/" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="32" height="32"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCS0HQwz4LWWGS4AZhb5Ry3w" target="_blank"><img src="images/youtube.png" alt="Youtube" width="32" height="32"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
    <nav id="page_nav">
      <div class="menu">
        <ul id="navmenu">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Get Involved</a><span class="darrow">&#9660;</span>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="socialmedia.html">Social Media</a></li>
              <li><a href="unionmeeting.html">Union Meetings</a></li>
              <li><a href="rally.html">Rally</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">News</a><span class="darrow">&#9660;</span>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="shrewsnews.html">Shrew's News</a></li>
              <li><a href="update.html">Update</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="contacts.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix">
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Andy, I hadn't noticed the error in the closing list tag.

Comment: the background colour still isnt going across though, clearly I have some other issue... they might just have to remain bullets

Comment: Andy you are brilliant, thank you that resolved my issue! Most appreciated!